# Expanding a frequency dataset for a single variable

Tags: python, arrays, count, histogram, frequency

I have 2 columns of data: One with Temperature values and the other with frequencies at which each temperature was observed. I have been trying to write code in python that takes this 2-column frequency data and creates an expanded array of the temperature data. I essentially want to reverse the process of "counting" the values and expose all the raw data values in a single array.

The way I am currently reading in the data is as follows:

```
f = np.genfromtxt('playground_sum.txt', usecols=(0,1))

freq = f[:,1]
temp = f[:,0]
freq = freq.astype(int)

new = []
for line in f:
    new = np.repeat(temp,freq)
print new
```

This worked! Any other methods welcome.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried yet? Also, if I understand what you want to achieve (display TEMP depending on the value of FREQ), why do you want to display `[10]` if the FREQ of 10 is 0?

Comment: @gk3rch You seem to have completely changed the format of your text file, and where does array() come from?

Comment: I apologize for the changes, I'm trying to show an example that's all. I'm coding in ipython notebook. The concept is what is important to me, not the numbers, input/output, format.

Comment: Do you have data in `.txt` format or you already have nested lists ?

Comment: I have data in .txt format

Comment: But as per your latest edit it says : `test = np.array([[15,0],[20,1],[25,2],[30,5],[35,0]])` which indicates that it is already a nested numpy array ?

Comment: In this example, yes this is a nested numpy array.

Comment: be clear on this ? do you want me to solve your problem in context with the `.txt` file or the `numpy` array.

Comment: The way that I am reading my text file, they are both numpy arrays. So in context to a numpy array please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array = []
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()[1: -1] # gives ex: '10, 0'
        try:
            temp, freq = [int(i) for i in line.split(',')] # a list comprehension
        except ValueError:
            continue
        array.extend([temp] * freq)
```

This assumes that each line in the file looks like this: `[10, 0]`

This code outputs a list looking like this: `[10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]`

Comment: should't you convert `freq` to int ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Totem solution, except I think you should convert frequency to integer.

```
array = []
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp, freq = line.split(',')
        try:
            freq = int(freq)
        except Exception as e:
            continue

        array.extend([temp] * freq)

print array
```

Comment: what's your data like ? That should be part `temp, freq = line.split(',')`  and reason is that it tries to split line but there is only one value in return so the other is `unpack`

Comment: I think the issue is because I'm using a numpy array?

Comment: you should update your question and append your current code there